# Create Gaussian dispersal kernel raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, create

In ArcMap 10.4.1 I would like to make a raster with a simple Gaussian distribution away from a central point - as in the image below. It does not need to be 3D, simply higher values at the centre and lower values to the outside. This will act as a null model to test against the actual distribution I found. The 'Create Normal Raster' function in Spatial Analyst appears to make a raster with randomly distributed values that over-all provide a normal distribution, but I want a surface that represents continuous dispersal away from a point.

[image: raster surface example]